# How to merge a Redis hash and a Rails record?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redis

For example, I have a shopping cart(redis hash) which contains a product id and a count:

```
{"165"=>"2", "166"=>"3"}
```

How do I find all products with these ids?
I think something like that:

1) `Product.where(id: hash.keys)` , but then I lose the `count`.

2) I can iterate the hash:

```
@products = []

hash.each do |id, count|
  product = Product.find(id)
  @products << product
end
```

But I don't know how to add count param in the `product` record and I think this approach is inefficient, because I'll get O(N) queries.

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get an array of arrays with two elements, where the first is the *product* and the second is the *count*:

```
Product.find(hash.keys).index_by(&:id).values_at(*hash.keys).zip(hash.values)
```

You can also add `.to_h` at the end if you want it to be a hash.

---

I would really not recommend this, but if you absolutely want the *count* to be added to the `Product`s themselves, you could use the result of the above and eigenclasses:

```
result.map do |product, count|
  product.define_singlethon_method(:count) { count }
  product
end
```

Comment: Does `where(id: hash.keys)` guarantee the order of the returned records matches the order of the ids in the input?

Comment: I can't get record attributes anymore. `undefined method id' for #<Array`. Btw, I need to pass this hash/array to JBuilder, but I don't know, is this possible to parse so complicated structure `[[156, #<Product id: 156, name: "magni"...], "2"]` to json?